# Apache Reverse Proxy Cookies not working

Tags: apache, nginx, cookies, proxy, reverse

following scenario:
I have a webservice running on port 81.
I want to use apache(nginx would also be okay) as reverse proxy, running on port 80 and redirecting mail.domain.com to port 81.

This is working so far.. but my webservice is telling me, that i should activate cookies. Without proxy it's working.

I followed a lot of tutorials etc., but none of the tips worked so far.

This is how my virtualhost looks:

```
<virtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / http://mail.domain.com

    ServerName mail.domain.com:81
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:81
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:81
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath http://myPublicIp:81 http://mail.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If someone has an easier way with nginx doing this, pls also tell me.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Why do you require cookies?

Comment: Because Axigen Mailserver uses it

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ProxyPass / http://mail.domain.com:81
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mail.domain.com:81
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain mydomain.com mail.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In your example, you are using the CookiePath which is modify the path in the cookie and not the domain.

Comment: your config redirects me to port 80 webserver, but not 81 as wanted.
changing ServerName to mail.mydomain.com redirects me to port 81.

Now my webservice on port 81 comes up, but the cookie message still appears... any way to change the cookies somehow? maybe by editing the cookie parameters

Comment: If you want to listen on port 81 you should change the VirtualHost to `*:81` instead of setting the server name to use port 81. Then Apache will proxy the requests to the mail.domain.com:81. But in your question you want apache to listen on port 80 and then proxy back to the mail server on 81. So the virtualhost that I created does that.

Comment: Right, thanks so far. So apache listening on port 80 should redirect to port 81 when subdomain mail. is called.
This works so far, but the cookies don't get accepted, which is my main problem.
Some parameters like 
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 
are needed, but I don't know how to set them.

Can please someone help me?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do 2 different things. Redirect is different than a proxy. With what you are trying to do is with the virtualhost is a reverse proxy where data is sent through apache to a backend and then returned back through apache and then back to the client. My answer above shows how to do that. You will have to verify that the reverse proxy is working and not a redirect. Then you can start testing out the cookies to make sure the mail .domain.com is setting them.